# DrRacket. Keybinding to join lines

Tags: racket

How can I make a keyboard shortcut in DrRacket to join the current and next lines without spaces between them? And when several lines are selected the command has to join them together.

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang
(keybinding "m:j" (λ (editor evt) 
  (define pos  (send editor get-start-position))
  (define line (send editor position-line pos))
  ...
  ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join lines with Alt+J keyboard shortcut.

Save the file and add it to DrRacket:

`Edit > Keybindings > Add User-defined Keybindings..`

Then restart the program.

```
#lang s-exp framework/keybinding-lang
(keybinding
 "m:j"              ; Join lines - Alt+J
 (λ (editor evt)
   ;;
   (define (join-lines start-line end-line)
     (cond [(>= start-line end-line) (void)]
           [else (join-with-next-line (sub1 end-line))
                 (join-lines start-line (sub1 end-line))]))
   ;;   
   (define (join-with-next-line cur-line)
     (remove-trailing-spaces cur-line)
     (define start-del-pos (send editor line-end-position cur-line))
     (define end-del-pos (send editor line-end-position (add1 cur-line)))

     (define text (send editor get-text start-del-pos end-del-pos))
     (define spaces (regexp-match #px"\\s+" text))
     (when spaces
       (define space-len (string-length (first spaces)))
       (send editor delete start-del-pos (+ start-del-pos space-len))))
   ;;
   (define (remove-trailing-spaces line)
     (define start-pos (send editor line-start-position line))
     (define end-pos (send editor line-end-position line))
     (define text (send editor get-text start-pos end-pos))
     (define spaces (regexp-match #px"\\s+$" text))
     (when spaces
       (define space-len (string-length (first spaces)))
       (send editor delete (- end-pos space-len) end-pos)))
   
   (define pos1 (send editor get-start-position))
   (define pos2 (send editor get-end-position))
   (define line1 (send editor position-line pos1))
   (define line2 (send editor position-line pos2))
   (define line1-end-pos (send editor line-end-position line1))

   (cond [(= line1 line2) (join-with-next-line line2)]
         [else
          (send editor begin-edit-sequence)
          (join-lines line1 line2)
          (send editor set-position line1-end-pos line1-end-pos)
          (send editor end-edit-sequence)])
   ))
```